Custom true nonce in conjunction with WP nonce in PWA
I'm looking for security advice on a nonce scheme I'm considering.
I have single page application with a WP backend. When the WP nonce expires, a page reload is necessary for the app to resume functioning. I am thinking I can avoid this by creating a table of true nonces. Here is the scheme.
The usual WP nonce is created and enqueued into the page. The front end script makes an ajax call for a true nonce, which can later authorize the one-time fetching of an updated WP nonce.
Currently I have a "heartbeat" type function that runs on an interval of about 3 seconds. When the script first starts, it records a start time. The heartbeat function checks current time against the start time and if it's been too long it pops up a notice and then forces a reload. Instead, I'd like the heartbeat to use a true nonce to fetch a good WP nonce along with another true nonce, then set the script start time to current.
This scheme means the app security token never gets stale, even if the user leaves the browser suspended for a month. It just tidies itself up in the first few seconds of waking up. Any failed fetch would trigger this check instantly. Unless connectivity was slow I wouldn't even alert the user.
Anyway, please let me know if I'm shooting myself in the foot, or defeating the whole purpose of the nonce. Thanks!

can you clarify what you mean by a "true nonce"? If it's to be taken literally it's a nonce value that can only be used once then is invalidated. Have you considered providing a refresh mechanism via REST API instead? Or using one of the existing systems such as OAuth/JWT etc? I'm also wondering how you would mark an answer as the correct/accepted answer, this looks less like a question and more like a discussion

the aim of the nonce is that a malicious website doesn't usurp the identity of the current connected user then it work also with your refresh system. but the classic wp nonce is valid at least 12 hours then I think you don't need to refresh it all 3 seconds.

Yes, by "true nonce" I mean precisely that, a number generated and stored in a table by the back end, and invalidated after a single verification.
Refreshing via REST still relies on network connectivity. This is my second commercial app. The first one had many users with old tabs open in their secondary device for many months. When they returned to that device, the WP "nonce" failed because too many ticks had elapsed. So they are now forced to refresh the page, which gets them a valid WP "nonce".  This scheme fixes that problem without seeming to open any greater attack vector than before.
